# How to check if a word in one csv exist in another column of another csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv file, one is dictionary.csv which contains a list of words, and another is story.csv. In the story.csv there are many columns, and in one of the columns contains a lots of words called news_story. I wanted to check if the list of words from dictionary.csv exists in the news_story column. Afterwards i wanted to print all of the rows in which the news_story column contained words from the lists of words from dictionary.csv in a new csv file called New.csv

These are the codes i have tried so far

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

news=pd.read_csv("story.csv")
dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv")

pattern = '|'.join(dictionary)

exist=news['news_story'].str.contains(pattern)
for CHECK in exist:
    if not CHECK:
        news['NEWcolumn']='NO'
    else:
        news['NEWcolumn']='YES'

news.to_csv('New.csv')
```

I kept on getting a nos eventhough there should be some trues

```
story.csv

news_url news_title news_date news_story
goog.com functional 2019      This story is about a functional requirement
live.com pbandJ     2001      I made a sandwich today
key.com  uAndI      1992      A code name of a spy
```

```
dictionary.csv
red
tie
lace
books
functional
```

```
New.csv
news_url news_title news_date news_story
goog.com functional   2019    This story is about a functional requirement
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of both files with expected output?

Comment: Pattern is a single long string with words combined with the pipe symbol. You are unlikely to find such a word in your news story. The straight-forward solution is to loop through the words in the first file and use `str.contains` in the body of the loop.

Comment: @jezrael you may see the edited example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column to Series with `header=None` for avoid remove first value with `squeeze=True` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv", header=None, squeeze=True)
print (dictionary)
0           red
1           tie
2          lace
3         books
4    functional
Name: 0, dtype: object

pattern = '|'.join(dictionary)
#for avoid match substrings use words boundaries
#pattern = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in dictionary)
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
exist = news['news_story'].str.contains(pattern)
news[exist].to_csv('New.csv')
```

**Detail**:

```
print (news[exist])
   news_url  news_title  news_date  \
0  goog.com  functional       2019   

                                     news_story  
0  This story is about a functional requirement
```

Comment: thank you very much this works! But, what if i wanted to keep the rows that does not have words exist in dictionary.csv in another csv file as well?

Comment: @strawberrylatte - then use `news[~exist].to_csv('New_not_exist.csv')`